# android expandable list from online database

Tags: android, database, expandablelistview

I'm designing an android app that retrieve universities from online database I have to use ExpandableListView to represent them.  I have 700 universities so I need to represent them by category . My categories are by letters  A,B,C,D etc.

```
>L
London Metropolitan University
Lea Valley College

>M
Manchester College
Manchester University
```

I have problem populating the child elements in each category. Because I have a lot of data I think the best way is when each category is pressed to create sql query to get all universities starting with 'A' for example  BUT all ExpandableListView  example I found use  arraylists or hashmaps with a few elements.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [CursorTreeAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html).

See [`getChildrendCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorTreeAdapter.html#getChildrenCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) method:

> If you want to asynchronously query a provider to prevent blocking the UI, it is possible to return null and at a later time call setChildrenCursor(int, Cursor).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, can you give some working example or tutorial how to use CursorTreeAdapter with online database because I couldn't find any :(